# 3 columns, left and right fixed with, centre fills remaining space

Tags: html, css

I realise this question has been asked a billion times, but none of the accepted solutions seem to work, so I'm going to try again.

How, using CSS, do I have 3 columns that fill the browser window, the left an right fixed at 200px and the centre one filling the remaining space?

This is very easily done with a table, but I have yet to find a method that works with divs and css.

Comment: `none of the accepted solutions seem to work` --> because you need to also to go to the other solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this with flex-box :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}

.border {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="border">Border</div>
  <div class="main">Center</div>
  <div class="border">Border</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's fantastic, and very easy, thank-you. How come most other 'solutions' I've found don't use flex? Is it a relatively new thing? Will there an issue with compatibility if I use it?

Comment: @MattGray some specific features of flex-box don't work well on IE. Check https://caniuse.com/#search=flex-box for compatibility. This code works even on IE so it works everywhere :p